# validate contents of arraylist against string

Tags: string, arraylist

I have an ArrayList and a string. I want to check and verify that all of the contents in the ArrayList are similar to the value of my String variable. If any of the value is not similar, the index number to be printed with an error message like (value at index 2 didn't match the value of expectedName variable):

```
ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
allNames.add("John");
allNames.add("John");
allNames.add("Jhon");
allNames.add("John");
allNames.add("John");
allNames.add("John");
allNames.add("John");

String expectedName= "John";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is just loop through every element in the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        allNames.add("John");
        allNames.add("John");
        allNames.add("Jhon");
        allNames.add("John");
        allNames.add("John");
        allNames.add("John");
        allNames.add("John");

        String expectedName= "John";

        for(int i = 0; i < allNames.size(); i++){
            if(allNames.get(i) != expectedName){
                System.out.println("Value at index " + Integer.toString(i) + " didn't match the value of expectedName variable");
            }
        }
```